# If I can get a US emergency passport in the UK, can I use it to travel to Poland and Spain?

Tags: uk, passports, us-citizens

I'm in London, would like to travel on to Poland and Spain, however my passport expires in slightly less than 3 months, which is a problem. I think I may be able to get something called an 'emergency passport' (emergency travel document?) from the US Embassy, but don't know if that will allow me to travel on into Poland and Spain. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Typically an emergency passport is intended to be used to travel back to your residence. You may be lucky in the Schengen zone that no one will be too interested in the details, or you might face additional questioning. Can the US Embassy not provide you with a standard ten year passport?

Comment: Why don’t you apply for a normal passport at the US embassy? I suspect that they can issue one within a 3 month period.

Comment: Thanks @Calchas I think the embassy can renew my passport, however I have a short window of a few days to continue this trip, and I believe they can't do a renewal that quickly. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Update: I received an emergency passport from the US Embassy in London - the process was very efficient and took slightly more than an hour. Passport control entering Poland took maybe 5 extra minutes scrutinizing my passport and asked why it was different, but then let me enter the country with no problems. Also no problems traveling on to Spain. Coming home to the states the automated passport scanner at the global entry kiosk in PHL wouldn't scan a passport without a chip, but it allowed me to manually enter the data.

Comment: Good to know. Could the US Embassy not provide you with a standard ten year passport in  a reasonable amount of time?

Answer (score 2):

Many countries do not allow emergency passports for entry, however it appears that both Poland and Spain do.

According to Timatic (the system most airlines use to verify visa/passport requirements), both countries do allow the use of emergency passports :

> Passport : Passport required.
>
> Passport Exemptions: Nationals of USA with an emergency passport.

From a validity perspective, all documents must have a validity of 3 months beyond your period of stay.

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a
>   minimum of 3 months beyond the period of intended stay.

Keep in mind that if you intend to enter the Schengen region via another country then you will also need to check their requirements as they could potentially be different (although in general most of the Schengen countries have very similar requirements)

Comment: Thank you @doc - this is very useful information.

Comment: Can I ask how you found this information? When I enter my travel information (assuming I'll get an emergency passport) into www.iatatravelcentre.com, it says I'm ok for Poland but Spain fails every time. I'm not sure where to find the "Exemptions" information for Spain.

Answer (score 1):

Poland and Spain both require passport validities of 3 months beyond the period of stay.

Emergency passports are issued for varying validity periods, usually up to [six months and occasionally more](https://www.livingthedreamrtw.com/2014/05/getting-emergency-passport-abroad.html).

If you get an emergency passport with validity three or more months beyond your planned stay then you are fine.

Comment: Thank you @musonius - I appreciate your help - I'm hoping this is exactly what happens :)